# Combining two list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, package

I have a class that produces a list from a model I created. 
List is generated using AppinioSwiper package.  
 Here is the code to the class created:

```
 import 'package:appinio_swiper/appinio_swiper.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 import '../../../blocs/national id/ghana_card_list_bloc.dart';
 import '../../../models/national id/ghana_card_model.dart';
 import 'ghana_card_front_list.dart';


 class GhanaCardList extends StatelessWidget {
 const GhanaCardList({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return StreamBuilder<List<GhanaCardResults>>(
  stream: ghanacardListBloc.ghanacardList,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(
          height: 200.0,
        ),
        !snapshot.hasData
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
            : Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                      height: screenSize.height * 0.6,
                      width: screenSize.width * 0.8,
                      child: AppinioSwiper(
                        cardsCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        swipeOptions: AppinioSwipeOptions.vertical,
                        loop: true,
                        allowUnswipe: false,
                        direction: AppinioSwiperDirection.top,
                        cardsBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return GhanaCardFrontList(
                            ghanacardModel: snapshot.data![index],
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                ],
              )
      ],
    );
  },
);
 }
}
```

I would like to combine the list created above with this list created here below. 
Here is the code to the second class with the list:

```
   import 'package:appinio_swiper/appinio_swiper.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   import '../../../blocs/card/card_list_block.dart';
   import '../../../models/credit card/card_model.dart';
   import 'card_front_list.dart';

   class CardList extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return StreamBuilder<List<CardResults>>(
  stream: cardListBloc.cardList,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(
          height: 200.0,
        ),
        !snapshot.hasData
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
            : Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                      height: screenSize.height * 0.6,
                      width: screenSize.width * 0.8,
                      child: AppinioSwiper(
                        cardsCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        swipeOptions: AppinioSwipeOptions.vertical,
                        loop: true,
                        allowUnswipe: false,
                        direction: AppinioSwiperDirection.top,
                        cardsBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return CardFrontList(
                            cardModel: snapshot.data![index],
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                ],
              )
      ],
    );
  },
);
  }
  }
```

How can I successfully achieve this/ I have tried everything I know and I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The list is a collection of data having the same data type.

In your case, you would like to combine lists of two different data types: *GhanaCardResults* and *CardResults*.

What you could do is using an abstract class

```
abstract class BaseCardResults {}
```

and extending it with the different types you need

```
class CardResultsTypeOne extends BaseCardResults {}
class CardResultsTypeTwo extends BaseCardResults {}
```

By doing this you can now have a list of data type *BaseCardResults* to which you can add *CardResultsTypeOne* and *CardResultsTypeTwo* objects.

```
final List<BaseCardResults> cards = [CardResultsTypeOne(),CardResultsTypeTwo(),CardResultsTypeOne(),CardResultsTypeTwo()]
```

The bloc manager should be the one that combines the two lists into one.

Once you have the list, instead of using *GhanaCardFrontList* and *CardFrontList*, you just need one widget that detects the data type of the card passed to it and build the widget accordingly

The widget might look like this:

```
  class CardFrontList extends StatelessWidget {
  final BaseCardResult card;
  const CardFrontList({super.key, required this.card});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: card.runtimeType == CardResultTypeOne
        ? _buildCardTypeOne(card: card as CardResultTypeOne)
        : _buildCardTypeTwo(card: card as CardResultTypeTwo),
  );

  Widget _buildCardTypeOne({required CardResultTypeOne card}) {
   /// build widget
  }
  Widget _buildCardTypeTwo({required CardResultTypeTwo card}) {
   /// build widget
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Here how you can use just one widget for showing the cards, following what I described previously.

Please note that now the bloc has to handle a list of BaseCardResults

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class CardList extends StatelessWidget {
 const CardList({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

 return StreamBuilder<List<BaseCardResults>>(
  stream: listBloc.cardList,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(
          height: 200.0,
        ),
        !snapshot.hasData
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
            : Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                      height: screenSize.height * 0.6,
                      width: screenSize.width * 0.8,
                      child: AppinioSwiper(
                        cardsCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        swipeOptions: AppinioSwipeOptions.vertical,
                        loop: true,
                        allowUnswipe: false,
                        direction: AppinioSwiperDirection.top,
                        cardsBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return CardFrontList(
                            baseCardResult: snapshot.data![index],
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                ],
              )
      ],
    );
   },
  );
 }
}
```

**Different approach**

A faster approach you could try in this case, since GhanaCardList and CardList are almost identical, is putting them into a **Stack** widget so that they are displayed one on top of the other.

```
class EntireCardList extends StatelessWidget {
 const EntireCardList({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            GhanaCardList(),
            CardList(),
          ],
        ),
     );
 }
}
```

I would anyway recommend you to handle it with just one list and just one widget, as described before, so that you don't have redundant code.

Comment: wow I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Just to be sure, you would like to show in the AppinioSwiper the entire list of cards, GhanaCardResults and CardResults, all together, right ?

Comment: yes please. Thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yeah so, you can just use one widget instead of two (GhanaCardList and CardList). If you notice, those two widgets are completely identical except for the data type of the list they handle and the widget for building the card ( GhanaCardFrontList and CardFrontList) inside the cardsBuilder property of the AppinioSwiper. I have added in the answer the only widget you could use for showing the entire list.

Comment: A different approach you could try in this case, since GhanaCardList and CardList are almost identical, is putting them into a Stack widget, so that they are displayed one on top of the other. I have added this approach as well in the answer.

Comment: i understand now. Thank you. I will give both a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254160/discussion-between-seyram-emmanuel-agbanyo-and-car-tor).